# upgrading spring-data-neo4j from 3.3.0.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Not able to import org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.Result.
I have code like - `Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query(matchQuery, null);`
Please let me know if api is deprecated/it name got changed in 4.0.0.RELEASE version. If i cant use org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.Result then what i have to use instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

`org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result` is the class to use in SDN 4.

BTW, SDN `4.1.1.RELEASE` is just out, it would be better to upgrade to that instead,

Comment: Thanks Luanne, will try that.